Is there a name for a function that is strictly increasing (or strictly decreasing) and that also goes through zero?
Consider a function $f(x)$, such that

$|f'(x)| > 0 $ - strictly increasing/decreasing
$f(0) = 0$

Is there a term used in literature to refer to this type of function?
Alternatively, is there a name for functions that satisfy the following (stricter) set of conditions?

$|f'(x)| > 0 $ - strictly increasing/decreasing
$f(x) = -f(-x)$ - odd

Example functions that would fall into these categories:

$x$
$x^3+x$
$-\arctan(x)$

EDIT:
Consider some arbitrary real function $g(x)$.
If I have a function $f(x)$ such that $f(0) = 0$ and $|f'(x)| > 0$, then I know that $f( g(x) )$ preserves the zeros and the stationary points of $g(x)$. Sometimes it is helpful to work with $f(g(x))$ instead of $g(x)$ directly.
So having a term to describe this kind of function would be quite helpful.

Why is it relevant to invent a name for such functions?

@SineoftheTime I edited the question in response to your comment. Does that answer your question?

I would choose, if given the opportunity, monotonic function.

@Hudjefa That sounds appropriate indeed, but it seems that monotonic is already reserved for functions that are both continuous and injective (or something of the kind), but the requirement $f(0)=0$ is not included.

How about decussate or simply SLASH functions?

I would call it a centrally symmetric monotonic function.
